# Bootstrap 4 - ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE (MaxCDN)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, security

I made an app in which Bootstrap is implemented. I copied the link from site like so.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">`

It worked at first, but then a few days later it stopped working. There was an error in the console that said `ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` and Bootstrap wouldn't load.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing `https` and changing the link to
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">`